# APIs to find mobile phone country Code and operator code

Tags: phone-number

I am looking for an API which can give me the countrycode and operator code for given mobile phone number, if any body has any leads please update.

It could be Database or API.
Ex:- I will give phone number as
Phone Number  : 97155xxxxxxxx
country code  : 971 and country is UAE
Operator Code : 55 operator name is "du"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no specific API which will provide the service provider and mobile number information , you can avail the paid service which will provide the all international phone numbers operators (HLR).

[Visit link for More Info](http://www.telecomabc.com/h/hlr.html)